# SRA Toolkit and lebanese data

Tags: fasta, phylogenetics, sratoolkit

I am trying to extract data from this:
https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR6245218

I installed SRA Toolkit, downloaded the SRR6245218 file and executed this:

```
fastq-dump -X 5 SRR6245218 --fasta -O ./
```

The result is a fasta file 900 bytes long, which does not contain the mitochondrial data that I need.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is fine. It is working as expected. Did you intend to include `-X 5` in your command? That restricts the number of spots to 5. If you drop it, you will download the entire set of 2563898 spots.

Comment: I see. I expected to get mitochondrion DNA. Not sure what I am getting here. But I already found it in fasta format somewhere else.